# How to evaluate these types of definite integral?

Tags: integration

$$\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{1}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{0}} \sin^{2k}\left(\dfrac{{\pi}}{2}x\right)\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x}$$.
I tried integration by parts but couldn't go far. The answer given in textbook is $$(2k)!/((2^
(2k))(k!)^2)$$

Comment: Integration by parts does work. Try harder.

Comment: Hint: $$\int s^{2k}dx=-cs^{2k-1}+(2k-1)\int c^2s^{2k-2}dx
\\=-cs^{2k-1}+(2k-1)\int s^{2k-2}dx-(2k-1)\int s^{2k}dx$$

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Wallis’integrals, as you can see by substituting $\frac{\pi}{2}x$ with $u$.

The given formula is obtained by induction.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: Thank you.  I solved it with your answer's  help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\dfrac{π}{2}x= u$
The integral becomes $$\dfrac{2}{π}\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \sin^{2k}(u)du $$
Using the definition of **Beta function**

$$\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \sin^{2m-1}(x) \cos^{2n-1}(x)dx= \dfrac{\Gamma{(m)} \Gamma{(n)}}{\Gamma{(m+n)}}$$

The integral is $$\dfrac{2}{π}\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}} \sin^{2(\frac{2k+1}{2})-1}(x)\cos^{2.(\frac{1}{2})-1}(x) dx= \dfrac{2}{π}\dfrac{\Gamma{(k+1/2)}\Gamma{(1/2)}}{\Gamma{(k+1)}}$$

Comment: Thank you. It is a nice way to solve it.